# Two foreach double, triple, quadruple ... the result

Tags: php, foreach

I have two arrays, one with the result of my SQL query, the other in the PHP code:

```
<?php
$test1 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
$test2 = array('a','c','g');
```

Quand je fais mes foreach cela me double les ou triple, quadruple ...les résultats...

```
foreach($test1 as $a1) {
    foreach($test2 as $a2) {
            if ($a2 == $a1) {
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='keyword' checked='checked' name='keyword[]' value='$a1'> $a1<br/>";
            }
            else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='keyword' name='keyword' value='$a1'> $a1<br/>";
            }   
    }   
}
```

The result is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVNoa.png)

Can you help me please ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: where is `$cat` defined ? It would be better if the code was closer to the image posted. Incidentally your HTML is not valid - ID attributes **must** be unique!

Comment: `name='keyword'` should also be as you have in the `if` as an array. It also would be much easier to just do `$checked = $a2 == $a1 ? "checked='checked'" : "";` then just use `$checked` in the element.

Comment: `foreach($test1 as $a1) echo "<input type='checkbox' id='keyword' " . (in_array($a1, $test2) ? "checked='checked' " : "") . "name='keyword[]' value='$a1'> $a1<br/>";`

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to know basically what you want to do. This is to print only the items in the **$test1** array.
- What you then want to do is to show that if an item is in the **$test2** array, it is marked.

The first thing you need to do you can do with foreach. But the second thing you want to do is actually look for a specific value inside an array.

You can use the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for that. Here is the code for what you want to do:

```
foreach($test1 as $a1) {
    if (in_array($a1, $test2)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='keyword[]' value='$a1'> $a1<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='keyword[]' value='$a1'> $a1<br/>";
    }
}
```